# Running Python code in VSCode - how to make the output more readable?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I write Python scripts using Visual Studio Code. When I run a script using CodeRunner, the output is nicely spaced and separated from output of previous runs, like this:

[image]

But, when I use the Python extension, the script runs in the terminal and appears much more cluttered:

[image]

There is no separation between runs, and it is much harder to read.

Is it possible, with the VSCode Python extension, to get the same nicely-formatted execution output as with CodeRunner?

Comment: Maybe add a print("\n") in the beginning?

Comment: @CozyCode I do not want to insert unneeded commands into each and every script I run...

Comment: i think ""terminal.integrated.lineHeight" setting in vscode is what may be looking for. this is just a guess though

Comment: @kamster Nice feature! But it spaces the lines even inside the program output, so it does not  help to separate outputs from two consecutive runs.